# Parent document ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, document-ready

I have a page embedded in a parent page via an iframe (same domain). jQuery is loaded in the iframed page, not in the parent page.

From within an iframe, I can use $(document).ready to know when the document is ready. But how can the iframed page know when the parent document is ready?

Comment: Is your base page and your iframe'd page on the same domain?

Comment: @ColinDeClue yes, see the question

Comment: @Christophe: Oh jeez. I read it like three times and didn't notice that. Whoo reading comprehension.

Comment: @JanDvorak Did you see Kevin B's answer? It doesn't seem to do what you think it will  do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Test the `readyState` property of `top.document` or `parent.document`. Using `$(...).ready` will actually listen for the ready event of the iframe, not what you pass into it.

Ref: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.9-stable/src/core.js#L254 (Notice how it never actually uses `this`, it just returns it for chainability)

For an example of how to actually listen for the event to happen or test if it has already happened, i'd suggest looking at how jQuery does it. https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.9-stable/src/core.js#L870 (replacing `document` with `top.document` where appropriate)

Comment: Thanks for the link, right to the point! That was my concern. Unfortunately I live with browsers that don't understand readyState...

Comment: Take a look at how jQuery does it: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.9-stable/src/core.js#L870 Since several different browsers/versions do it differently, i'd rather defer you to one that works than try to create a sample myself.

Comment: So basically you're saying that jQuery won't help with this and I should just use plain JavaScript?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what i'm saying. jQuery doesn't have much that will help here. You could use jQuery's event handling though, `$(top.document).on("DOMContentLoaded readystatechange load",...)` but you'll have to first make sure that it isn't already ready.

Comment: Looking at the core, it appears as though `top.document.readyState === "complete"` should work in all browsers.